# STM32F103 MPR121 SPL library

Tags: stm32, i2c

I'm trying to drive an MPR121 capacitive touch sensor module. It works fine on Arduino. Here is my Arduino code:

```
Wire.beginTransmission(0x5A);
Wire.write(0x00);
Wire.endTransmission(false);
Wire.requestFrom(0x5A, 1);
if (Wire.available() < 1)
  return 0;
return (Wire.read());
```

However I can't read register 0x00 with STM32F103. I can read an EEPROM with the same read function and different address, using the STM32. The wires have been checked a thousand times. STM32F103 I2C Config:

```
I2C_DeInit(I2C1);
i2c.I2C_Mode = I2C_Mode_I2C;
i2c.I2C_DutyCycle = I2C_DutyCycle_2;
i2c.I2C_OwnAddress1 = 0xEE;
i2c.I2C_Ack = I2C_Ack_Enable;
i2c.I2C_AcknowledgedAddress = I2C_AcknowledgedAddress_7bit;
i2c.I2C_ClockSpeed = 10000;
I2C_Cmd(I2C1, ENABLE);
I2C_Init(I2C1, &i2c);
I2C_AcknowledgeConfig(I2C1, ENABLE);
```

STM32F103 I2C read function:

```
uint8_t read_e(uint8_t addr){
uint8_t Data = 0;
I2C_GenerateSTART(I2C1, ENABLE);
while(!I2C_CheckEvent(I2C1, I2C_EVENT_MASTER_MODE_SELECT));
I2C_Send7bitAddress(I2C1, 0x5A, I2C_Direction_Transmitter);
while(!I2C_CheckEvent(I2C1, I2C_EVENT_MASTER_TRANSMITTER_MODE_SELECTED));
I2C_SendData(I2C1, addr);
while(!I2C_CheckEvent(I2C1, I2C_EVENT_MASTER_BYTE_TRANSMITTED));
I2C_GenerateSTART(I2C1, ENABLE);
while(!I2C_CheckEvent(I2C1, I2C_EVENT_MASTER_MODE_SELECT));
I2C_Send7bitAddress(I2C1, 0x5A, I2C_Direction_Receiver);
while(!I2C_CheckEvent(I2C1, I2C_EVENT_MASTER_RECEIVER_MODE_SELECTED));
I2C_AcknowledgeConfig(I2C1, DISABLE);
while(!I2C_CheckEvent(I2C1, I2C_EVENT_MASTER_BYTE_RECEIVED));
I2C_GenerateSTOP(I2C1, ENABLE);
Data = I2C_ReceiveData(I2C1);
return Data;  
}
```

and finally the while(1) code:

```
buffer = read_e(0x00)
```

and print buffer through uart.

---

STM32 EEprom I2C signals on logic analyzer:

[image: STM32 EEprom I2C signals on logic analyzer]

---

Arduino MPR121 I2C signals on logic analyzer

[image: Arduino MPR121 I2C signals on logic analyzer]

---

and STM32 MPR121 I2C signals on logic analyzer:

[image: STM32 MPR121 I2C signals on logic analyzer]

Comment: Your stm32 code is drastically incomplete.  You should determine if the I2C operation is or is not acknowledged.  Make sure you actually have pull-up resistors.  A cheap USB based logic analyzer can be useful but only a scope can see analog issues.

Comment: @ChrisStratton added.

Comment: That's a good start, now use the analyzers i2c decoder or at least make the timescales the same so that you can readily compare, especially up to the point where it looks like the stm32 doesn't get an ack for the address.  Keep in mind there are two traditions for specifying address as a number but they should be the same on the wire.